# jQuery template() for putting a URL into src= attribute of image

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

i have a jquery template:

```
<div id="test_template">
    <img src="${url}" width="31" height="32" alt="" />
    ${url}
</div>
```

I compile it with this:

```
test_template = $('#test_template').template();
```

I render it with this:

```
$.tmpl(test_template, {url:'http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png'}).appendTo('#render_test');
```

the end result is this:

```
<div id="render_test">
<img height="32" width="31" alt="" src="$%7Burl%7D">   http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png</div>
```

obviuosly I expected the URL to be in the src="" tag... but it is not (though it IS being outputted correctly after the  tag).  if I look at the anonymous function created by template(), I see that it isn't turning the src="${url}" into javascript.  it is just encoding it as HTML and spitting it back out

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest version of the templates plugin, I have no issues using the latest plugin and either jQuery 1.4.2 or 1.4.3.

[You can see the working demo of your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Tgwcd/).

Comment: Thanks Nick.   If I change my template wrapper to use  <script id="test_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> instead of a <div>... then it works!  I literally downloaded the template plugin an hour ago, but let me make sure  I have latest

Comment: nope, I have jquery 1.4.2 and I just got the template code from here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.min.js ... still not working (unless I use the <script> tag).  why does yours work and mine not?

Comment: @Nick - Probably the context it's in, the browser's already trying to do something with the source of that template.  I *would* use a `<script>` tag to be safe, so the browser doesn't even *try* to parse the content.

Comment: good point... that's ultimately the right answer anyways.  thanks!

Comment: yes, but look at what happens in ff4 with that same jsfiddle link, you get the escaped template code, ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> what am I doing wrong?

Using a real `<img>`.

When you use attributes like `<img src>`, the browser may fix up your values to make them valid. So because the characters `{}` aren't valid in a URL, the browser may encode them to `%7B%7D`. This is probably browser-specific; Nick's example that he says works fails for me in Firefox. (It also fails in IE due to the missing `var` on `test_template`, but that's an unrelated issue.)

Remember when you write HTML elements, the HTML source is not maintained. The browser will parse it into a load of DOM nodes. When you call `html()` (`innerHTML`) what you get is a serialisation of those DOM nodes, which does not exactly preserve the formatting of the original markup. Especially when the original markup isn't really valid HTML but just a placeholder for templating.

For this reason I would not use actual in-page elements to template from, and I consider jquery-tmpl's encouragement of this with its `$(element).template()` method to be a mistake. That's not the only issue I with the plugin. For example if you put `data()` or an event handler on an element inside the template, that data/handler gets copied accidentally on IE but not other browsers, due to naïve `innerHTML` copying and jQuery's horrid node-identity hack.

So if you must use `jquery-tmpl`, use strings with it, not nodes. Use strings embedded in a `<script>` if you have to, but don't use actual in-page elements. (As well as this problem, it's also semantically questionable to have content in the document that isn't actual content.)

Answer (score 0):

I fix that with an ugly hack that uses TmplItem :

```
        function fixRenderedTemplate(rendered){
            var fixArray = [["img", "src"], ["a", "href"]];
            for (var i=0; i<fixArray.length; i++){
                var tagName = fixArray[i][0];
                var attrName = fixArray[i][1];
                $(tagName, rendered).each(function(index, elem){
                    var data = $(elem).tmplItem().data;
                    var fixTemplate = unescape($(elem).attr(attrName));
                    var url = $.tmpl(fixTemplate, data).text();
                    $(elem).attr(attrName, url);
                });
            }
            return rendered
        }
```

Just call the function on your rendered template